# load an image when app launch - Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I set an image like this to my view:

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map3.jpg"]];
```

Right now I have it in a button action method. But how do I make it set directly when the app is launched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the `backgroundColor` of a `UIViewController`'s view, then move your code into `viewDidLoad` and adapt likewise:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map3.jpg"]];
```

A `UIViewController` doesn't have a `backgroundColor` directly, but its view does, like any other `UIView`.

Comment: Still, unless you actually have a pattern image (ie an image that tiles and repeats) you should be using a `UIImageView`.

Comment: Or do `self.view.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"map3.jpg"].CGImage;`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to put that logic within your view controller's -viewDidLoad method for the UIImageView property.

Comment: sorry I wrote the question wrong. I do not have an imageview. I'm setting the image as backgroundColor to my view. How should I do then?

Comment: Then set the backgroundColor in the viewDidLoad method. It still is the appropriate place.

Answer (score 1):

UIView

If you are in a `UIView` class place the code in either `initWithFrame:` or `initWithCoder:`

`initWithFrame` gets called when you instantiate the view from code (e.g. `UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`
`initWithCoder:` gets called whenever the UIView is loaded from an XIB file.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

UIViewController

If in a `UIViewController` a common place to put it would be in `viewDidLoad`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html